strcpy clears source string after copying content to destination string
int main(void)
{
    char u[12], v[12], w[12];
    int i;

    srand(time(NULL));
    for(i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        u[i] = rand() % 95 + 33;
    }
    u[i] = '\0';

    strcpy(v, u);

    strncpy(w, u, 5);
    w[5] = '\0';
    
    return 0;
}

So I have written the code above. My problem now is, that after running strcpy(v, u), u gets cleared entirely for some reason. I'm very new to C so I have no idea how to fix this.
Tried researching my issue on several sites but I did not find any solution.

Where do you think, the terminating 0 byte for your strings should go? You only reserve 12 elements in your array and fill it with 12 random characters. Increase the arrays to size 13.

u[i] = '\0'; you writing past array boundary.

Also, strncpy is a bit tricky. If n is too big, dest isn't null-terminated. If n is too small, dest gets filled up with zeroes. Both can be surprising to someone who hadn't actually read the function's documentation...

here is the online demo of your code https://onlinegdb.com/98ijUCjjFW. u is not "cleared". why so?

@DevSolar Nobody ought to use strncpy in the first place. Unix fixed width strings went obsolete... somewhere in the 1980s? I'm pretty sure they were obsolete before C89.

@Lundin Unfortunately strncpy looks like the logical partner to e.g. snprintf (to safely avoid buffer overflow), which unfortunately it isn't.

@DevSolar It should never had made it to the C standard in the first place. It's one of many shortcomings of the C standard lib. It would seem that the C89 committee filled a hat with the names of random smelly Unix functions, then picked a number of them to become the fancy new standard lib.

@Lundin Those were the days when languages were developed in the wild, not the lab. "Existing practice" and all that.

Whenever I check out an issue, the first thing I usually do is compile the program and review the compiler log for any warnings.  After adding in the necessary "#include" directives, I compiled your code example.  In the compiler log, the following warning provides a clue as to what is noted in the good comments added to your issue.
    /home/craig/C_Programs/Console/RandomChar/main.c|15|warning: array subscript 12 is above array bounds of ‘char[12]’ [-Warray-bounds]|

As noted, that would most likely be your first clue that some type of undefined behavior was going to happen when running your program.
With that in mind, following is a refactored version of your program to address the issue of going past the boundary of your character array(s).
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

#define SIZE 12

int main()
{
    char u[SIZE], v[SIZE], w[SIZE];
    int i;

    srand(time(NULL));
    for(i = 0; i < (SIZE - 1); i++) {
        u[i] = rand() % 95 + 33;
    }
    u[SIZE - 1] = '\0';

    strcpy(v, u);

    strncpy(w, u, 5);

    w[5] = '\0';

    printf("u: %s  v: %s  w: %s\n", u, v, w);   /* See the results  */

    return 0;
}

Some things to note about the refactoring.  First off, I utilized a "#define" directive to mitigate the use of hard-coded or "magic" numbers in the program.  Next, since the ultimate number of random characters to be utilized was five characters, I just made sure that the string length boundary was not exceeded when generating a string containing random characters.  With that, following are a couple of test runs of the refactored code.
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/RandomChar/bin/Release$ ./RandomChar 
u: }E{]oLHWv((  v: }E{]oLHWv((  w: }E{]o
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/RandomChar/bin/Release$ ./RandomChar 
u: o9haex5`q{n  v: o9haex5`q{n  w: o9hae

The main takeaways from this would be to always review your compiler logs for warnings as they can indicate possible undefined behavior, and remain careful in allocating enough memory for the size of your variables.
